# Dividing clock frequency and then phase shifting it

Tags: clock, phase-shift

I have a 60MHz source clock. I need to create four 15MHz clocks aligned with the source clock, such that each next clock is phase shifted by 90 degrees from the previous one. How can I achieve this? Is there any IC for such task?

Comment: 'm' for milli, 'M' for mega, 'Hz' for hertz please.

Comment: Should be doable with few flip-flops and inverters. What have you tried so far? What needs this kind of clock?

Comment: FPGAs can do this.  

https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug472_7Series_Clocking.pdf

Comment: @Justme I was thinking about flip-flops. But how can I align their output with source clock? (I'm doing basically a demultiplexer of a video signal. So I need to divide pixel clock by number of recievers)

Answer (score 2):

A divide by 4 needs to be synchronous at these speeds sharing the master clock to minimize phase skews from the expected 90 deg shifts relative to the % of 16.67 ns per phase.

But you need to specify this maximum skew to choose the right parts and configuration.

Simply:

60 MHz /2 using D FF with Q,Q! With 2 clocks Driving 2 more /2 D FF’s gives 4 quadrature outputs but with some potential skew from unequal worst case skew from Clock to Q & Q!.  Recall Q! loop back to D gives /2 f outputs.

74ALV14 might be adequate or better use CML logic family.

Comment: Maximum skew is about 4.5% (0.8 ns)

Comment: Next you have to read datasheet and decide on max ambient temp effects and decide which is best

Comment: But will this circuit be aligned with the source clock?

Comment: The output clocks will be aligned with the source clock in the sense that an oscilloscope looking at the source clock and some output clocks, syncing on an output clock, will show everything holding still from sweep to sweep. The skew could be minimized by feeding the output clocks to a register clocked by the source clock.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need output clocks to rise at the same time as source clock

Comment: Wires/gates always have delay, so you'll either need to accept some delay or add a compensating delay to the source clock.

Comment: You must define the tolerances with latency and skew  by design specs. Now! In Q.

Comment: The only design constraint is that rising edge of the each generated clock should appear no more than 0.8 ns away from rising edge of source clock

Comment: Now you can read the datasheets and the choice should be obvious from my suggestions.

Comment: I think you need better specs, cost, voltage, jitter etc. Do you know how to use the NB4L52? https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/nb4l52-d.pdf  Do you know how to design with 4GHz logic?

Comment: No, is there any good tutorial?

Comment: No you need to learn how to learn !